# nuget packages sans pdb files

Tags: c#, debugging, nuget, package

Following on from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764572/using-nuget-symbols-servers) it seems to me the "value add" of nuget is greatly dimished when pdb files are not available.

Example: I set up my c# project with references using nuget. I start coding and cannot work out why an external package is throwing an error. I want to debug. If that package has no pdb files I am out of luck. Well sort of. I can go ahead and download the source code for that package and build it myself. Thats no problem, but then I have to go through and change my references in my project to point to this source. Hmm, I must be missing something. Otherwise its just faster to manage external references myself. I must be doing it wrong.

**UPDATE:**

So my question is: How do people work with nuget, and debug when the nuget package doesn't have pdb files? Or best way to debug 3rd party libs when using nuget.

**UPDATE 2:**

I am not sure why this question got down voted? Maybe I didnt phrase it correctly. In a nutshell how do people work with packages delivered via nuget that dont have pdb files. And they want to investigate why their code throws an error?

I am not bagging 3rd party libs or OSS or nuget - I just want to make sure I am using nuget correctly.

Comment: I think it would be better to phrase this as a proper question.

Comment: Fair nuff....question updated with clearer question ;-)

Comment: Bugs in third party libraries are relatively rare, especially the popular ones. I think this is a niche requirement. Maybe I'm a bit spoilt in the sense that ReSharper decompiles code from third party assemblies for me which, coupled with the fact that bugs in third party libraries are relatively rare, means I get enough insight into the library's behaviour without much effort. It's possible you'd be better off reading the documentation for the third party library and getting a better understanding of how to use it, before using it.

Comment: Mate, I think you missed the point of my question. Sometimes to get better understanding of a library one may want to decompile the said lib as well as step through it. All code has bugs, and sometimes you need to be able to step through to see where the bug is. Usually the person using the library is doing something wrong, but that doent mean there is no need to be able to step through code. Maybe next time get off your high horse and read my question properly.

Comment: Hi, you seem to have invested some thought in nuget vs pdb files a while back - maybe you want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643871/nuget-c-packages-partitioning - cheers.