# Copy NuGet .pdb to output directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, pdb-files

When I build an ASP.NET Core project it copies to the output directory only its own `.pdb` files and all .`dll`s of any installed NuGet packages. However, it does not copy their `.pdb` files. I have to select them manually from the `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages` directory.

I was wondering whether there is an option to enable NuGet package `.pdb` to be copied to the output directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new way of doing this is, increasingly, to use [SourceLink](https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink), which allows source code to be downloaded on demand while debugging.

> **NOTE:** At the time of this writing there are still [missing features](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458), as pointed out by Martin Ullrich.

### NuGet Symbols Packages and Symbols Servers

Traditionally, there were no `.pdb` files in NuGet `.nupkg` files.

Instead, the `.pdb` files were put into [NuGet symbol packages (ending in `.symbols.nupkg`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages).

They can then be hosted on [symbol servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14764623) (or the local file system), which can in turn be used by the Visual Studio IDE by [configuring it accordingly](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio). See also [Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger).

Do note that not all NuGet package publishers create symbols packages or use SourceLink - if you need to debug an open source library that doesn't have any, perhaps you should consider contributing them.

Comment: Actually they are my own packages that contain `.pdb` files but the alternative with the NuGet symbol packages (which is new to me) sounds very interesing and it looks like the right way for using `.pdb` files.

Comment: I'd actually say that including the pdb files is increasingly the better way of handling this - using [Source Link](https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink) to link the PDB to the source code itself. This removes the dependency on the symbol servers.

Comment: It's actually a missing feature and should be available in 2.1.300+, see tracking issue https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458

Comment: @nl-x: If the approach in the answer doesn't work for you, I'd need to look into exactly what's going on. But be aware that not everything needs to be in an *output* directory for .NET Core - I'd expect it to possibly not be there, but be in a *publish* directory. So try running `dotnet publish` and see whether that's any better.

Comment: @nl-x: Using SourceLink, I'd expect the PDB to be in the NuPkg file already - for example in the NuPkg file for https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1/. If the package's publisher didn't use either symbol servers or include the PDB file in the package, that's not something that can really be fixed by the consumer. But if the PDB file *is* in the package already, I'd expect the debugger to be able to pick it up. At this stage I think you'd be best off asking a new question describing your exact situation, rather than doing it in comments here.

Comment: @nl-x: Again, please ask a new question, describing your exact situation - what you've tried, and what's not working. Normally this just works out of the box.

Comment: @nl-x: How do you know their exact situation? You don't know what version of .NET they're targeting, what packages are involved, exactly what happened when they started debugging, etc. At least, none of that information is in the existing question. That's what should be in your new question. Please, please do not add any more comments on this answer, unless it's a link to a new question. Stack Overflow comment threads are not designed for this sort of extended discussion.