# How to get nuget pdb into output build of application

Tags: c#, nuget, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48854021/2334520) but I don't think it answers my question.

The `nuget`s I use do have their own `.snupkg` symbol package. And when I ship my application, I don't just want to ship my own `pdb`s but also the `nuget` ones. But I can't seem to get the `pdb` files be compiled into the output folder of my `exe`.

Comment: [PDB files are symbol files for the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file). They aren't much use for release builds. Are you sure you want to ship them to customers?

Comment: it's for crash reports that they give a more broad idea of where the error occurred. I don't write any security- or business-relevant software where I need to obscure my callstacks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464271/include-nuget-dependencies-in-my-build-output) Q/A help?