# Can I configure Visual Studio to allow debug step into NuGet packages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

I am using a NuGet package in an internal project.  (The NuGet package is EPPlus, fwiw.)

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to allow debug step into the NuGet package?

I'm using VS Community Edition 2019 (v16.2.0), and the EPPlus NuGet package (v4.5.3.2)

I've found a number of posts about how to clonethe NuGet package and then either rebuild it from scratch, or include it in an existing VS project, and then trace into it, but that is not generally useful.  (And can be a rathole unless the NuGet project is well maintained and well designed.)

I'm looking for something closer to how debug symbol files can be installed to allow stepping into Windows API code.

Is there something similar for refernced NuGet packages?  Is it as simple as asking the NuGet package maintainer to checking the pdb files along with their source?

Comment: Reflector, dotPeek come to mind - given a DLL, they can generate .PDB and the associated code. BUT the package you are mentioning seems well maintained on GitHub (https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus), so downloading soruces and building it yourself is your best bet.

Comment: [related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764572/using-nuget-symbols-servers) Depending on whether or not the package maintainer has a symbol package configured.